# Can't poll from S3 with a custom endpoint configuration

Tags: java, amazon-s3, spring-integration, minio, spring-integration-aws

I try to use `spring-integration-aws` to poll from a S3 bucket to trigger a spring-batch job. My S3 bucket is not hosted on Amazon, it's on a local minio server, so I got a custom configuration :

```java
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3(ConfigProperties configProperties) {

        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:9001","eu-west-0")) // Region matches with minio region
                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(configProperties.getS3().isPathStyle())
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                        configProperties.getS3().getAccessKey(), configProperties.getS3().getSecretKey()
                ))).build();
    }
```

I defined my IntegrationFlow this way :

```java
  @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow s3InboundFlow() {

        S3RemoteFileTemplate template = new S3RemoteFileTemplate(new S3SessionFactory(amazonS3));
        S3StreamingMessageSource s3StreamingMessageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(template);
        s3StreamingMessageSource.setRemoteDirectory(String.format("%s/OUT/", configProperties.getS3().getBucketDataPath()));

        return IntegrationFlows.from(s3StreamingMessageSource, configurer -> configurer
                .id("s3InboundAdapter")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(POLL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(jobLaunchingGateway(jobRepository)) // Launch a spring-batch job
                .get();
    }
```

The problem is, when the polling occured, I got the following error :

```
2020-03-30 19:05:21,008 ERROR [scheduling-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler:  org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: S3 client with invalid S3 endpoint configured: localhost:9001
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:342)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: S3 client with invalid S3 endpoint configured: localhost:9001
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getRegion(AmazonS3Client.java:4270)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3Session.getHostPort(S3Session.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:214)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:359)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
```

It happens because when the file is received, some headers are set in `spring-integration-aws` :

*AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java*

```java
return getMessageBuilderFactory()
            .withPayload(session.readRaw(remotePath))
            .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE, session)
            .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, file.getRemoteDirectory())
            .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, file.getFilename())
            .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_HOST_PORT, session.getHostPort())
            .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE_INFO,
                                    this.fileInfoJson ? file.toJson() : file);
```

The `REMOTE_HOST_PORT` header is set thanks to *getHostPort()* method. The *getHostPort()* in *S3Session.java* then calls the *getRegion()* method.

The *getRegion()* method in `AmazonS3Client` is not checking if a value is set by the user in `signing region` field. It only checks if the host is matching the "amazonaws.com" pattern.

```java
@Override
    public String getHostPort() {
        Region region = this.amazonS3.getRegion().toAWSRegion();
        return String.format("%s.%s.%s:%d", AmazonS3.ENDPOINT_PREFIX, region.getName(), region.getDomain(), 443);
    }
```

```java
   @Override
    public synchronized Region getRegion() {
        String authority = super.endpoint.getAuthority();
        if (Constants.S3_HOSTNAME.equals(authority)) {
            return Region.US_Standard;
        } else {
            Matcher m = Region.S3_REGIONAL_ENDPOINT_PATTERN.matcher(authority);
            if (m.matches()) {
                return Region.fromValue(m.group(1));
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "S3 client with invalid S3 endpoint configured: " + authority);
            }
        }
    }
```

How is it possible to poll from S3 with a custom endpoint configuration ? 
Why is the *getHostPort()* method not checking the *signing region* value ? Is it possible to workaround this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to workaround.
You just extend an `S3SessionFactory` to return an extension of `S3Session` with overridden `getHostPort()` method for your custom endpoint.

```java
public class MyS3SessionFactory extends S3SessionFactory {

    private MyS3Session s3Session;

    @Override
    public S3Session getSession() {
        return s3Session;
    }

    public MyS3SessionFactory(AmazonS3 amazonS3) {
        super(amazonS3);
        Assert.notNull(amazonS3, "'amazonS3' must not be null.");
        this.s3Session = new MyS3Session(amazonS3);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyS3Session extends S3Session {

    public MyS3Session(AmazonS3 amazonS3) {
        super(amazonS3);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHostPort() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Let's discuss a possible fix in the issue you have raised: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/160 !

Comment: Thank you, your workaround works perfectly. Yes, let discuss the issue on Gihub